# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID{} failed

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, com, components, clsid

I have two projects in the same computer that use the same dll (InputsSanitizer), the only difference between them is one is in IIS 7 and is a website, and the other one is not in IIS 7 and is a webapplication.

The one in IIS 7 is giving me this error:

[image]

The other one has no error at all, any advice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x80040154 is [`REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542643%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG), "Class not registered".  {CE32ABF6-475D-41F6-BF82-D27F03E3D38B} stands for CAPICOM, a discontinued, 32-bit component.

I'm most sure this is a bitness mismatch problem.  Recompile your project targeting x86 and enable 32-bit application in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Enable 32-Bit Applications in the IIS Application pool.

Hope this help someone else.